# Get security key (String) from Server, to use it in Swift

Tags: swift, encode, secret-key

I have a file on my server(linux) with a key (something like: asdfadsfadsf) inside, this key changes all 2 hours. Is there a secure way to pull that key from my server, to use it in my swift application? The key is not really that secret and no one could do bad thing with it.. But I would like how to deal with that.

Encode it on the server and Decode it in the application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the key unique per user?  If not then SSL/TLS is sufficient to transfer it securely.  If it's unique per user then you'll likely want to do some sort of public key encryption.

Comment: no its not unique.. They key just expires every 2 hours

Comment: How can I transfer it over SSL/TSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement an API in the server for the app to call and get the content(e.g. your key) whenever the app or the logic needs.

> The key is not really that secret and no one could do bad thing with it.

Then a HTTPS API call is more then enough.

> Encode it on the server and Decode it in the application?

If it is a plain key and not that secure like you mentioned. Encoding and decoding are probably not needed.

Comment: I actually got it already working. But thanks for your answer!  I put the key on a JSON with auth. and then I just GET it from there over my application! works like charm :)